# Angular 8 upgrade - typescript error - Type 'Observable<XYZ | Observable<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<XYZ>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I had a perfectly running code (and still running perfectly). When I upgraded from angular 7 to angular 8,  my visual studio code started showing errors for HttpClient.get methods.

The errors are coming in the catch part of the HttpClient.get method. Code is compiling fine and working fine as well. I checked angular examples and everything looks correct. I am not sure why editor showing issues.

```
     getLaborStats(dt: string, hotelId: string): Observable<LaborStats> {
    let lastDayLaborURL = HelloGMVars.varServiceURL + 'laborstats' ;
    const options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().append('AccessToken', this.accessToken)};
       return this.httpC.get<LaborStats>(lastDayLaborURL + '/' + hotelId + '/' + dt, options)
     .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getLastDayLabor', null))
     );
     }
```

Here are the errors my editor is showing -

```
"[ts]
Type 'Observable<LaborStats | Observable<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<LaborStats>'.
  Type 'LaborStats | Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'LaborStats'.
    Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'LaborStats'.
      Property 'today' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.
(method) Observable<LaborStats>.pipe<LaborStats | Observable<any>>(op1: OperatorFunction<LaborStats, LaborStats | Observable<any>>): Observable<LaborStats | Observable<any>> (+10 overloads)
"
```

If I remove the .pipe part, then errors go away. So, it tells me that something is problem in the catchError part.

Here is my error handler -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable ,  of } from 'rxjs';

import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { OktaAuthService } from './services/okta-auth.service';

/** Type of the handleError function returned by HttpErrorHandler.createHandleError */
export type HandleError =
  <T> (operation?: string, result?: T) => (error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable<T>;

/** Handles HttpClient errors */
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorHandler {
  constructor(private okta: OktaAuthService, private messageService: MessageService) { }

  /** Create curried handleError function that already knows the service name */
  createHandleError = (serviceName = '') => <T>
    (operation = 'operation', result = {} as T) => this.handleError(serviceName, operation, result);

  /**
   * Returns a function that handles Http operation failures.
   * This error handler lets the app continue to run as if no error occurred.
   * @param serviceName = name of the data service that attempted the operation
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  handleError<T> (serviceName = '', operation = 'operation', result = {} as T) {

    return (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<T> => {
      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      const message = (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) ?
        error.error.message :
       `server returned code ${error.status} with body "${error.error}"`;

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.messageService.add(`${serviceName}: ${operation} failed: ${message}`);

      if (error.status === 401) {
        console.log('401 returned so logging out') ;
        this.okta.logout() ;
      }
      // Let the app keep running by returning a safe result.
      return of( result );
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify your error handler strategy. It looks like you're using catch and replace.
Make sure your `handleError()` function throws an Error as follows:

```
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // Error handling here
    // rethrow
    throwError('Cannot perform the request, please try later');
  }
```

Import `throwError` from RxJS:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: added my error handler which is based on reference provided on angular website.